# How to implement a fixed header toolbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a fixed header bar which works in all type of browsers and mobile browsers.

In the below code, is it possible to avoid the attribute `style="padding-top:100px"` in the `div` element of the content. I don't want to manually compute the `100px` of distance.

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="xheader" style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:1000; border:solid 1px red">
        <p>FIXED BAR</p>
    </div>

    <div id="xcontainer">
        <p>Line1</p>
        <p>Line2</p>
        <p>Line3</p>
        <p>Line4</p>
        <p>Line5</p>
        <p>Line6</p>
        <p>Line7</p>
        <p>Line8</p>
        <p>Line9</p>
        <p>Line10</p>
        <p>Line11</p>
        <p>Line12</p>

        <p>Line1</p>
        <p>Line2</p>
        <p>Line3</p>
        <p>Line4</p>
        <p>Line5</p>
        <p>Line6</p>
        <p>Line7</p>
        <p>Line8</p>
        <p>Line9</p>
        <p>Line10</p>
        <p>Line11</p>
        <p>Line12</p>

        <p>Line1</p>
        <p>Line2</p>
        <p>Line3</p>
        <p>Line4</p>
        <p>Line5</p>
        <p>Line6</p>
        <p>Line7</p>
        <p>Line8</p>
        <p>Line9</p>
        <p>Line10</p>
        <p>Line11</p>
        <p>Line12</p>

    </div>

</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class for that div with 
`padding-top: 100px`
otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

Because the header element is taken out of the flow of the document (by `position:fixed;`) you do need *something* to push the content below the header.  But you can use a more flexible unit than pixels:

```
padding-top: 1.5em;
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVFRh/1/).

Since ems are relative to the parent's font size, the padding here will scale up or down a different font size.  Or you can just use `%` to specify the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do that with jQuery:

```
var xheaderHeight = $('div#xheader').height();
$('div#xcontainer').css('padding-top',xheaderHeight);
```

Thanks for your responses.